# namespace name 'p' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working in a generic method in order to deserialize an xml document depends on the contain. It tries to deserialize all posible cases.

Here my code snippet:

```
 private static Dictionary<Type, byte> getMessageDictionary() {
     Dictionary<Type, byte> typesIO = new Dictionary<Type, byte>();
     typesIO.Add(typeof (Type1), 1);
     typesIO.Add(typeof (Type2), 11);
     typesIO.Add(typeof (Type3), 12);

     return typesIO;
 }

 public static object GetContainer(XmlDocument xd) {
     foreach(KeyValuePair<Type, byte> item in getMessageDictionary()) {
         try {
             Type p = item.Key;
             var z = Utils.XmlDeserialize<p> (xd.OuterXml);

             return z;
         } catch {
             continue;
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

But the compiler says the type or namespace name `p` could not be found. Do I miss a `using` directive or an assembly reference? What went wrong?

Comment: You cannot use an object of type `Type` in a context where a type is expected. The type argument of a generic class/method has to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` is a variable containing a reference to a `Type` instance, but you are trying to use it as a type parameter.

To do what you want, you'll need to invoke the method using reflection:

```
Type p = item.Key;
var method = typeof(Utils).GetMethod("XmlDeserialize").MakeGenericMethod(p);
var z = (XmlDocument)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { xd.OuterXml });
```

Comment: I haven't any MakeGenericType(p), I have MakeGenericMethod() but when i use it it throws an InvalidOperationException with the message  bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which containsgenericparameters is true... any sugestion? thanks for reply

Comment: @Mirlo - Yes you're right, it should be `MakeGenericMethod`. What is the type of `p` you are passing to `MakeGenericMethod`? If is contains generic parameters (e.g. `typeof(IEnumerable<>)`) then you will get the exception you describe. You'll need to supply the type parameters to `p` first before you try call `MakeGenericMethod`.

Comment: Ok, in the end i used something similiar but the answer was very useful thank you.